# If click on Save/Publish change Post Status to Pending Review instead Publish

Tags: functions, publish, post-status

Here's my problem. I need following solution.

If a user is in the admin area of Wordpress and is not an administrator - and creates a page or product(via WooCommerce) - that if this user clicks on the blue "publish" button, the page/product should goes into the status "Pending Review", no matter what is selected in the status option or if it is already a published page/post/product whatever. If the blue published button gets clicked, by a non-admin, it always should go to pending review status.

[image]

I already fixed the problem with Javascript, but well the User could simply manipulate it - So I am searching for a PHP function.

Here is my current script made with Vanilla JS

```
add_action( 'init', 'savePendingReview' );
function savePendingReview() {
    if(is_admin()) {
        global $pagenow;
        if(!current_user_can('administrator') && 'post.php' === $pagenow) {
            echo '<script>
            window.addEventListener("load", function() {
            document.getElementById("post_status").selectedIndex = "1";
            </script>';
        }
    }
}
```

As you see my Javascript solution is pretty dirty. Any ideas how I can fix the problem with PHP? I need to hook into the save_post action to change the post_status.

Comment: You need to look into permissions - roles and capabilities. First check what WooCommerce comes with; they may already have a built-in role. If not, you could use a plugin like User Role Editor that will allow you to grant and remove the specific capabilities - here you need the users to be able to edit whatever the post type for a product is, but not be able to publish them, and there are several others such as edit private products you'll need to decide whether to grant or not. Or, you can create your own plugin that builds the role you want with the capabilities you want.

Comment: Hello @WebElaine thanks for the fast response. I already tried out the Plugin "User Role Editor" By Vladimir Garagulya - The role already have the correct capabilities, but it does not solve the problem. I need the user to be able to change any of their posts/pages/products, they should have the rights to edit them all - but if they save it it should go on the status pending review, I do not know if its possible to setup with this Plugin.

capabilities:
1. Assign product terms
2. Edit product
3. Edit products
4. Edit published products
5. Manage product
6. Read products

Comment: So, just so I understand correctly: You want to achieve this behavior even if a product or page is already published, meaning when a non-admin makes a change and saves it, then page would effectively become unpublished?

Comment: @WSU yes, you understand it correctly . The users see only their own pages/products/posts, and if they make a change, I need that the page gets unpublished/ gets the post status "pending review".

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a solution for that. It also doesn't sound like the best solution for your customers that products keep appearing/disappearing. This is especially because you also don't have any way to track what changes have been made. If I were in your position, I'd try to find a different solution. Sorry that I can't be of any help here.